# Setting a property hidden by control's interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I am attempting to set a System.Web.UI.Control object's ID field. The control implements an interface, IChartControl, which does not have an ID property. I would like to retrieve the control as an IChartControl and set its ID field.

Should I do this?:

```
IChartControl chartControl = foo.GetChartControl();
(chartControl as Control).ID = foo.GetID();
chartControl.Bar();
```

or would it be equally right to add a new property to IChartControl named 'ID' so that when I set the ID field it sets Control's ID field.

Comment: If you cast like that you'll get a null reference exception if, touch wood, `chartControl` isn't a `Control`. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to cast the object to the type that has the member you want to set, as you have in your code example.

Adding an `ID` property to `IChartControl` will work, but only do it if it makes sense in the context of this interface. This will indeed allow you to set the `ID` property without needed the cast.

So long as the `ID` in the interface and in `Control` are the same ones, you should be fine. Where you can get into trouble is if you try and use [explicit interface implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Comment: Why would it conflict? As long as the signatures matched, adding the IChartControl to a class that derives from Control would just have its ID member "automatically" implemented.

Comment: @dlev - You are quite right. I was thinking about explicit interface implementations which, depending on how the class was implemented could have surprising results.

Comment: very true. Tried to edit my comment in response to your edit, but apparently you can only edit comments for 5 minutes. Now I just look silly!

Comment: @dlev - People can still see my edits, and there is nothing wrong with looking silly every now and then ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should only add an ID field to `IChartControl` if you feel that all `IChartControl` implementations should support retrieving an ID value. If that's the case, then adding it makes sense. If not, then the `as` statement is fine (though risky, since `GetChartControl()` only guarantees an object that may or may not have an ID, and may or may not be a Control.)